# What does the performance of computer processes depend upon?

Tags: ssd, cpu, speed, processing

I was very curious as to what really is responsible for processes like starting of tomcat server or npm install from Nodejs? I was under the impression that just a fast SSD is sufficient to do this but apparently I was wrong. In spite of running these processes on machines with fast SSDs, these processes do not run as fast as they do on machines with better processors. How much does a processor affect the above mentioned processes?

**Specs:**
Both Systems had the same following config:

- 16 GB DDR3 1600 MHz Memory
- 512 GB Samsung 850 EVO SATA III SSD
- Windows 10 Pro
- No discrete graphics

**The only difference was one was Intel 5th Gen Core i5 and the other was same generation Core i7 (Albeit Quad Core)**

I am skipping other irrelevant specifications like display, cooling systems, etc.

EDIT: I do **not** want a generic answer. I want answer specifically for the above two processes.

Comment: That depends on the kind of process. If they compile modules, JIT code CPU does have a significant impact. For others it might be the speed at which files can be loaded in RAM because they do a lot of caching upfront.

Comment: Oh, so then the RAM will also play a part in this?

Comment: @ashhem everything plays a part. If the program is large then both disk and ram, if the program has a lot of calculations then cpu and ram, a lot of graphics then disk, cpu, gpu and ram. Everything affects how programs start up and run and you can't easily generalise without knowing what exact program and what exactly it needs when starting up.

Comment: @Mokubai, I specifically need for the processes I have mentioned above.

Comment: @ashhem is the entire system running from a fast SSD or just these programs? It would be worth posting your system specifications (and maybe the "fast" system as well) and rephrasing your question very slightly.

Comment: @Mokubai, done :)

Comment: @Mokubai, sorry forgot to answer this, the entire system is.

Comment: Nobody can give you an answer "specific for the processes mentioned above" because different systems may have different performance bottlenecks even when running the same processes. If this is on Windows, use Resource Monitor to see which resources (CPU power, storage I/O bandwidth, RAM, etc.) are maxed out. Be aware that when you address one bottleneck (for example by adding RAM) you are likely to reach a different bottleneck beyond that.

Comment: Interesting thought Jamie. I mean yeah, there is a change that it may result into a cycle of upgrades where upgrading one component would result into other component being the reason for bottleneck,